# Requirement already satisfied al ejecutar pip install --upgrade pip

Tags: python, windows, pip, certificado-ssl

La cuestión es que no puedo actualizar el pip utilizando el comando:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Pues me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\ksmc\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
Collecting pip
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:992)')))
```

Lo mismo me pasa si intento instalar librerías de python como numpy, pandas, etc.

En el portátil en cambio no me pasa y no encuentro la solución.

Answer (score 0):

El error que estás recibiendo indica que hay un problema con la verificación del certificado SSL al intentar descargar los archivos necesarios para actualizar `pip` o instalar nuevas bibliotecas de Python. Esto puede deberse a varios factores, como una conexión a Internet inestable, un firewall que bloquea las conexiones SSL o una configuración de proxy incorrecta.

Para solucionar el problema, puedes intentar lo siguiente:

Asegúrate de que tienes una conexión a Internet estable y que no hay restricciones de firewall que bloqueen las conexiones SSL.

Intenta agregar el argumento `--trusted-host` a tus comandos de `pip`. Por ejemplo, para actualizar pip, puedes usar:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade pip
```

Esto debería permitir que pip descargue los archivos necesarios a través de una conexión SSL no verificada.

Si tienes una configuración de proxy, asegúrate de que esté configurada correctamente en tu entorno de Python. Puedes hacer esto agregando la variable de entorno `HTTP_PROXY` y `HTTPS_PROXY` a tu sistema, o estableciéndolas en tu archivo de configuración de Python.

Si el problema persiste, puedes intentar actualizar `pip` manualmente descargando el archivo de instalación desde el sitio web de Python y ejecutando el archivo descargado en tu sistema. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, sigue igual. Saliendo el mismo mensaje. No sé cómo configurar el proxy. Soy nuevo en esto. La cosa es que en el portátil no he tenido ningún problema.

Pero aquí sigue saliendo el mismo problema, y la verdad no sé a qué se debe.

Comment: Intenta `python -m pip install --upgrade certifi`, igual intenta esto: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`